Laravel 11 & Passport - "No Supported Authentication Provider Found for Token" Error
I’m using Laravel 11 with Laravel Passport 11.x to handle API authentication. I’ve set up Passport for OAuth2 authentication and personal access tokens. However, I’m encountering the following error when attempting to authenticate using a personal access token:
InvalidArgumentException: No supported authentication provider found for token.

I’ve followed the official documentation to set up Passport in my Laravel 11 application.

I’ve published the migrations and run php artisan migrate to create the necessary tables.

I’ve also installed Passport using php artisan passport:install.


The application is running on PHP 8.1.
What could be causing this error, and how do I fix it?
I’m trying to authenticate a user using a personal access token with a request to a protected route.
Here’s my code for generating the token in the AuthController:
use Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessTokenResult;

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        $token = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')->accessToken;

        return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}

And the code for the protected route:
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->user());
});


have u changed driver in config file?

Please review the following points and comment below if everything is configured correctly:

Set up guards in config/auth.php for Passport
Ensure you have configured the guards for Passport in the config/auth.php file. Refer to the example below:

'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport', /** For Passport */
    'provider' => 'users2',
],


Set up providers in config/auth.php for Passport
Configure the providers in the config/auth.php file for Passport. Here's an example:
'users2' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
],


Generate Passport keys
Ensure the Passport keys are generated in the following paths:

storage/oauth-private.key
storage/oauth-public.key

Assign the appropriate permissions to these files, such as 600.

Manually generate keys if not created automatically
If the keys are not generated automatically, you can forcefully generate them using the following command:
php artisan passport:keys --force


Load Passport keys in the AppServiceProvider
In the boot method of app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php, load the Passport keys as shown below:
public function boot(): void
{
    Passport::loadKeysFrom(base_path('storage'));
}


Clear cache and restart the application
After completing the above steps, clear the cache using:
php artisan optimize:clear

Then, restart your Laravel application.


If you encounter any issues after these configurations, feel free to comment below. I’ll be happy to assist you!
